# SQLAlchemy: does Column with ForeignKey creates index automatically?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Does Column with ForeignKey creates index automatically?
Or I need to do that manually adding `index=True`?

```
some_field = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(SomeModel.id))
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You do need to either specify `index=True` or create an `Index` object explicitly:
`Index('myindex', mytable.c.col1, mytable.c.col2, unique=True)`, which allows more control over other parameters of the index, such as the name and support for more than one column.

See [Indexes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/constraints.html#indexes) for more information.

Comment: Sqlalchemy won't do that for you, but mysql's Inno engine will do this automatically.

Comment: Is this true for primary keys too?

Comment: @BerislavLopac: I believe most (if not all) RDBMSs do create index for primary key automatically.

Comment: @van: Postgres will *not* create indexes on foreign keys for you, unlike MySQL's InnoDB engine.

Comment: @van Your comment is really interesting to me and I appreciate it!  Does anyone have information specific to SQLAlchemy, Postgres, and whether indexes are created for `primary_key=True` ?  Specifically, I mean tables created by ORM **without** `index=True`

Comment: @blong: see this answer, which covers it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42899045/99594

Answer (score 2):

As van's answer indicates, **you should explicitly add an index** as indicated by the docs.

The implementation of foreign keys is database specific, and some DBs such as MySQL *will* still automatically create an index for foreignkey column, but others will not. See discussion in comments above.

e.g from [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-foreign-key.html):

> MySQL requires that foreign key columns be indexed; if you create a
> table with a foreign key constraint but no index on a given column, an
> index is created.